# I eat the potato because I like potatoes!

Tags: grammar, tense

I've been doing German lessons on [duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com), and this is one of the questions that came up:
[image]

This got me puzzled. What does "I eat the potato" even mean? I imagined a huge house-sized potato that I'm getting a slice of every now and then. "Oh yeah, the potato is at the main square, everybody in the village eats it. I eat the potato too! It is nutritious and it never ends! It just grows back!"

So it sounded quite off to me and I decided to do some research. First off, I entered the expected German answer into Google Translate:
[image]

Did these guys used Google Translate to author the lesson? Google cannot be wrong, right?

Unsatisfied, I [searched ngram for 'I eat the'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+eat+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20eat%20the%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20eat%20the%3B%2Cc1). Well there were quite a few hits, but the examples were like:

- I cut down what I eat the next day
- The less I eat, the better I feel
- Shall I eat the ice cream sundae?
- I eat the way my parents eat
- I eat the right kind of foods

None of which is similar to the phrase in question. [I eat the potato](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+eat+the+potato&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) does not return any results.

Is this usage correct?

Comment: The third example sentence you presumably got from Google Books features a definite article whose usage is similar to the one in the sentence in question. Don't use the Google Ngram Viewer for this purpose in the future.

Comment: Don't stress too much about this example sentence.  It is strange English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement **“I eat the potato because I like potatoes”** is grammatical but  not idiomatic, and by that I mean English native speakers wouldn't talk about a single countable item of food using the definite article in that type of construction.

Countable noun   “apple”

> 1. I eat **the** apple because **it** keeps the doctor away. (non-idiomatic)
> 2. I eat **an** apple a day because **it** keeps the doctor away. (Yes) ✔︎
> 3. I eat **the** apple because I like it. (possible)
> 4. I eat **the** apple [the fruit] because **it's** healthy. (non-idiomatic)
> 5. I eat **apple** [its substance/taste] because I like **it**. (Yes) ✔︎
> 6. I eat **apples** because I like **them**. (Yes) ✔︎

Uncountable noun “fish”

> 1. I eat **the** fish because **it** keeps the doctor away. (non-idiomatic)

Between fish and another food, e.g. cheese, the speaker selects *the* fish, and explains why it was chosen.

> 2. I eat **a** fish because I like fish (non-idiomatic)

If we consider [**fish**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fish_1) as an animal (*a fish*) it is countable.

> 3. I eat **fish** because **fishes** are healthy. (depends on the context…)

However, fish is also an uncountable noun when we consider its flesh as a source of food and it is only pluralized when we are talking about different species of fish.

> 4. I eat **fish** because **it's** healthy. (Yes) ✔︎

Grammatical and idiomatic.